# Azure Notification Hub Client run time error

Tags: azure

Downloaded latest Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs NuGet package used the NotificationHubClient to create an installation this.HubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallation(installation);

All the default dependent packages were used when adding the NuGet.  When testing I am receiving the following error:

****Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)****

I assume this is widely used.  How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

This is version conflict issue. Remove all your old version package and reinstall Microsoft.Extensions.Options, it will work